# modifying a logic network

Tags: logic, computer-science, boolean-logic, circuit

We are given a logic network and told that gate 3 fails and produces the logic value 1 at its output F1 regardless of the inputs. We are then told to redraw the network, making simplifications wherever possible, to obtain a new network that is equivalent to the faulty network and contains as few gates as possible. Then we are told to repeat this problem, assuming that the fault is at position F2, which is stuck at the logic value 0.

Here is the network picture: https://gyazo.com/f5c23a97d2be53160b4702722c314178

[image]

I am confused on this since I have plugged in values into x1 and x2 and got that 3/4 combitinations give me that 1 they were talking about. I guess my problem is that I don't see how to simplify this. I am new to circuitry and drawing logic networks.

Answer (score 0):

The following transformation rules have to be applied to propagate the effect of assumed stuck-at faults:

[image: List of transformation rules]

This list could be extended to gates with more than two inputs. The order of inputs does not matter.

If `F1` is fixed to value `1`, you can omit gate `[3]` and all wires going into `[3]`. Gate `[4]` is turned from a `NAND2` into an inverter. You can merge it with gate `[2]`, because `NAND2` + inverter is an `AND2`.

After `F2` is fixed to `0`, output `f` solely depends on input `x4`. Inverter `[5]` can be omitted as its output is fixed to `1`. Therefore, `AND2` gate `[6]` can also be omitted, as an `AND2` with one of two inputs a fixed `1` simply becomes a buffer or a wire. `x4` directly feeds `OR2` gate `[8]`.
`F2` `0` implies that the output of `AND2` gate `[7]` is `0`, independent of `x3`. Hence, `OR2` gate `[8]` has one `0` input which can be omitted. As a consequence, output `f` must be equal to input `x4`.

Comment: The first portion of this makes sense. I am struggling with the second part. How come output `f` depends on input `x4`? If this is the case then, can't we get rid of that OR gate? I am having a hard time drawing the resulting Logic Network.

Comment: Yes. You can simply connect `x4` to `f`. If `F2` is fixed to `0`, influence of `x3` is masked out and the value of `x4` is directly forwarded to output `f`.